# Zorin OS: wifi adapter not detected on laptop

Tags: wifi, zorin

I have an internal Wi-Fi adapter in my laptop, but suddenly for seemingly no reason whatsoever, it stopped being detected. All of the other questions that are about this aren't working. I use a Dell laptop, but I don't know which type of Dell it is. It all happened after my computer shut itself off trying to save itself from overheat. I fear I may have to replace my current computer. I don't even know what internal Wi-Fi card it is, in fact! I just need help with this. If you are wondering how I connected to Stack Exchange, I used my phone as a USB tether.

Comment: Overheat... May be a dead wifi card... Try `lspci` to see if the OS find your wifi adapter. Don't you have some kind of Bios hardware tests available at boot time ? Often, wifi are on Mini PCI-E format and quite easy to replace, not matter the model. If you need it, buy a good linux compatible one.

Comment: Is the "Network Adapter" thing the Wi-Fi card? I'm not sure

Comment: Often, you may have one or two nic on a laptop. One for Cable connection, and another for WiFi connection. It is possible to miss one, or to have other ones more. How to know ? Can't you tell us more from your hardware ? Could you try installing inxi with `apt install inxi` then run it with `inxi -Fxz` in a terminal, then paste the result (edit your question). Well, just try running it, then install it if it fails...